# Get unique values from multidimensional array object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, unique

I want to get a unique "STATE" value from the multidimensional array object.

I have checked this

```
_personsList = [
    {"name":"Joe", "age":17}, 
    {"name":"Bob", "age":17}, 
    {"name":"Carl", "age": 35}
];

_uniqAgeList = _.groupBy(_personsList,"age");
_uniqAges = Object.keys(_uniqAgeList);
console.log(_uniqAges);
```

but it seems it's not working for me.

and distinct() is also not working.

Here what I get the response.

[image: Response]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using underscore.js or lodash?

Comment: You say you want a unique `STATE` but your array has `name` and `age`.

Comment: underscore has been dead for years @Barmar

Comment: wait... is underscore alive again somehow?!

Comment: In your screen shot, the array is in the `data` property of the object. Did you access it correctly? Show the code that processes your actual response, not the array from some other question you copied.

Comment: @NaftaliakaNeal does not mean people stop using it. ;) Got people using 10+ year old  versions of jQuery

Comment: Do you even need a library? `Array.from(new Set(_personsList.map(p => p.age)))`